# Programmatically setting the content of a ContentControl in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a UserControl  named "WorkspaceView" and its only purpose is to show other views as tabs. Call these views ViewA, ViewB etc. Which of these views to present should be determined on runtime, so I figured I needed a control that can present ... well ..stuff. 
ContentControl to the rescue. Except ... I can't make it work. I'm trying to new up a usercontrol of type ViewA in the code behind and assign it to my MyContent, which is the ContentControl. I've tried:

```
public WorkspaceView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new View(A); //Hoping that the DataContext will propagate down
}
```

Second attempt was

```
public WorkspaceView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var binding = new Binding {Source = new ViewA()};
    MyContent.SetBinding(ContentControl.ContentProperty, binding);
}
```

In both cases, I see an empty box, but since I've hard wired a TextBlock into ViewA, I'd expect it to show me that text. What am I doing wrong?

Despite knowing that MVVM is the preferred way to develop WPF applications, I'd prefer to see how I can do this with code behind files. Later on, I will redo the application with MVVM, but first I need to get some basic understanding of WPF.

In response to the suggestions so far, I've tried

```
MyContent.Content = new ViewA();
```

but still I the text that is in ViewA does not appear. I've also at the bottom of this post included a screenshot of what the application renders.

### WorkspaceView

[image]

### Resource file

[image]

### What is rendered

[image]

Comment: Remove all your `DataTemaplates` and your second approach or better `MyContent.Content = new ViewA();` should work (i mean it will answer the question in the title).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried simply doing this?

```
MyContent.Content = new ViewA();
```

**EDIT**

Try simplifying your code a bit and working from there. For instance:

```
public WorkspaceView()
{
   InitializeComponent();

   // Something better than UserControl should be used here
   ObservableCollection<UserControl> views = new ObservableCollection<UserControl>();
   views.Add(new ViewA());
   views.Add(new ViewB());

   DataContext = views;

}

<Border ..>
    <TabControl x:Name="TabControl"
       ..
       ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
</Border>
```

This code sets a `WorkspaceView.DataContext` to a collection of `UserControls`. When you specify `{Binding}` whithin `WorkspaceView`'s XAML you are refering to the whole `DataContext` object (i.e. your collection.) This way you are setting the `TabControl.ItemsSource` to your collection of views.

Now you could create `DataTemplates` targeting the type of each view to control how each control is displayed in its tab within the `TabControl`.

Comment: Nope, hadn't tried that, but now that I've done so, it unfortunately doesn't work :(

Comment: Could you update with details after trying that? I think that the problem resides in your WorkspacesTemplate.

Comment: Your value `ItemsSource` in `TabControl` is `{Binding}`. That would imply that the `DataContext` of the `TabControl` is some sort of collection. Well is it ? Because if it isn't, it won't show anything, beacuse the `TabControl` is just empty. Besides your `ClosableTabItemTemplate` is empty so it won't show anything. It would be really helpful if you could provide us with your project, because we can't really see what's going on in the rest of the classes.

Comment: Also, I`ve found out that when learning complex nested controls like this one (a template, within a tabcontrol that is a template, which is a template of `ContentĆontrol`) it's really good to learn by doing it step by step: Create a `ContentControl` with a template that is a simple `TextBox` and bind it to some simple string. See if it works. Move on.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm learning as we go. According to @MikeWazowsky, the the DataContext of the TabControl should be some sort of collection, but it's not in my case. I didn't know that it had to be, so in WorkspaceView I removed the reference to the ContentTemplate, i.e. now it reads **<ContentControl x:Name="MyContent" />** The application still doesn't render anything.

Comment: The `DataContext` in `TabControl` doesn't have to be a collection. `ItemsSource` binding should point to a collection.

Comment: Yes!!! After my last reply, I realized that I had only tried setting the DataContext of the WorkspaceView and that I hadn't tried Jnovo's suggestion. After having done Mycontent.Content = new ViewA(), the text is displayed. That suggests that my ContentTemplate is not working correctly. I have no idea why it isn't working, but at least I now know where to look.